# Is there a CRLF after the message-body?

Tags: http, httpresponse

I don't know if after sending all the bytes of the body I should send the next message without a CRLF separating the body of the first message from the start-line of the second message.

This is the syntax according to RFC 7230:

```
 HTTP-message   = start-line
                  *( header-field CRLF )
                  CRLF
                  [ message-body ]
```

According to the syntax there is no CRLF at the end of the body, but it looks odd since everything else seems to be separated by a CRLF specially the syntax for the chunked body.

```
 chunk          = chunk-size [ chunk-ext ] CRLF
                  chunk-data CRLF
```

This is how it looks without the CRLF:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 3

abcHTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 3
```

And this is how it would look with it:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 3

abc
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 3

abc
```

So, should a CRLF follow the body?

Comment: How often do you "look" at keepalive streams between HTTP servers and browsers? Because that's the only time you would "see" two concatenated HTTP messages, and browser and server can figure out the syntax pretty well. **Why** do _you_ want to add a newline between them?

Comment: It is easier for me to read with the CRLF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [It is easier for me to read with the CRLF.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30433224/is-there-a-crlf-after-the-message-body/30435091#comment48953536_30433224)

Then you must include it in the message body:

> [RFC 7230, 3.5.  Message Parsing Robustness](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.5):

> An HTTP/1.1 user agent MUST NOT preface
> or follow a request with an extra CRLF.  If terminating the request
> message body with a line-ending is desired, then the user agent MUST
> count the terminating CRLF octets as part of the message body length.

Answer (score 5):

No, when content-length is present, and chunked transfer encoding is not in use, the body has exactly the length defined by content-length.

Comment: I know that the CRLF should not be inside the body, I am asking if you could add one following the body.

Comment: The HTTP message ends with the last bytes of the body.